# Copying Values From One Col to other automatically and making it fixed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So basically, I want first entered value of ColI in ColJ automatically that is if ColI is not empty the value in ColI should be in ColJ but it should be fixed that is, if in future Value in ColI changes or goes blank the ColJ value should remain the same.

I have attached a sample sheet in this sheet

Link [Please feel free to make a copy] - (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jHi49EGPO3vmGXDzKl1LeDOjKFtA5XYug7Gd7vtFtUs/edit#gid=0)

I have been struggling on this from sometime. Plz Help. THANKS! :)

Comment: Edit your question to make it more clear. Add a screenshot of the input (or the data before) and the expected output ( the data after). You will make the life of the answerer easier and you will get an answer faster

Comment: Usually when I want to use formula only once I then Copy it's result and paste values only (Ctrl +Shift +V)

Comment: I want it automated thats the thing :(

Comment: What do you mean "a static if statement"?

Comment: I don't even think that it is possible with an if statement. It would require app scripts